# ¿Como tener en una celda del encabezado varias columnas para un reporte con fputcsv PHP?

Tags: php, csv, report, fputcsv

Estoy generando un reporte y existe una celda del encabezado, en donde sus registros deben ser varias columnas.

Ejemplo de como quiero tenerlo
[image: Requerido]

Ejemplo de como me sale actualmente

[image: actualmente]

De que manera puedo combinar esas celdas?

Anexo codigo que estoy utilizando

```
<?php

$arraydata   = [];
$consultaArreglo    = [];
$arreglo_encabezado    = [];

//----- Creamos el encabezado -----//
$arreglo_encabezado = ["Transaccion","Estado","Detalle" ];

//----- Creamos la Data-----//
$array1 = ["1","Recibido","Validado","Confirmado","Exitoso"];
$array2 = ["1","Recibido","Validado","Rechazado","Error"];
$array3 = ["3","Recibido","Validado","Confirmado","Exitoso"];

array_push($consultaArreglo,$array1);
array_push($consultaArreglo,$array2);
array_push($consultaArreglo,$array3);

//----- Creamos archivo temporal y escribimos en el csv -----//
$tmpfile = tmpfile();
$tmpfile_path = stream_get_meta_data($tmpfile);      
$fp = fopen($tmpfile_path['uri'], 'wb');

//----- Guardamos encabezado -----//
fputcsv($fp, $arreglo_encabezado, ';');

foreach ($consultaArreglo as $line)
{
    $line=(array)$line;  
    $line=join(";",$line)."\n";
    fwrite($fp, $line);
}
```

?>

Comment: Una forma sería iterar el encabezado de esa que se duplica tantas veces resultados exista también. O hacer que ese campo internamente sea más bien separado con comas o punto y coma de esa forma pudieras editarlo abajo al descargarlo.

Comment: En los archivos CSV no existe la posibilidad de dar formato, por lo que... o creas esas "celdas" vacias o creas otro tipo de archivo (XLS, XLSX, ODS, etc.)

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, y si justo eso pensaba que el file Csv solo es texto separado por ;

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de utilizar la función `fputcsv`, se debe implementar otra libreria o metodos para manipular la estructura, ya que esta función no permite combinar celdas o tener un control avanzado sobre el formato.

Te recomendaria pasarte a: `PHPExcel` o `PhpSpreadsheet`

***Implementacion:***

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

Ejemplo (intentando recrear tus datos):

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv;

// Crear una nueva hoja de cálculo
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

// Definir el encabezado
$encabezado = ["Transaccion", "Estado", "", "", "Detalle"];
$sheet->fromArray($encabezado, null, 'A1');

// Definir la data
$data = [
    ["1", "Recibido", "Validado", "Confirmado", "Exitoso"],
    ["1", "Recibido", "Validado", "Rechazado", "Error"],
    ["3", "Recibido", "Validado", "Confirmado", "Exitoso"],
];

// Calcular el rango de celdas para combinar la columna "Estado"
$numFilas = count($data);
$rangoEstado = 'B2:B' . ($numFilas + 1);
$sheet->mergeCells($rangoEstado);

// Llenar la data
$sheet->fromArray($data, null, 'A2');

// Guardar el archivo CSV
$writer = new Csv($spreadsheet);
$writer->setDelimiter(';');
$writer->setEnclosure('');
$writer->setLineEnding("\r\n");
$writer->setSheetIndex(0);

$filename = 'reporte.csv';
$writer->save($filename);
```

La columna "Estado" se combina para cada fila de datos utilizando `mergeCells()`, y luego los datos se escriben utilizando `fromArray()`.